# How to put repeat images over a gradient shape in Android?

Tags: android, image, gradient, shapes

I have this code in xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#222288"
    android:startColor="#9966cc" />
```

How I can add a repeated image over the gradient? Is for a background layer of a Android project.
Something like this but for Android:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #666;
background-image:url(repeated_image.gif)
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have my answer using a layer-list with the shape and the bitmap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="#222288"
            android:startColor="#9966cc" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/repeated_image"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
</item>
```